# How's stack implemented by java?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I'm not asking how to implement stack in java, but how the stack class is implemented by java? 
Does it use linked list?
If so then if I know exactly how many elements I'm gonna deal with, isn't it better to mimic a stack using an array, it will be faster than how java implements stack class?

Comment: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Stack-source.html

Comment: Not familiar with Java, but usually stacks are implemented as a linked list, for flexibility. You certainly could use an array if you want. Again, not familiar enough with Java to know if it's faster to use an array, but I'd imagine it's kind of up to you. C++ I know it probably wouldn't really matter, so I don't see why not Java.

Comment: Sounds like a premature optimization. Don't create your own stack implementation unless you _really_ need to. Chances are your implementation will have more errors .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html the Stack class is derived like this:

```
 java.lang.Object
    java.util.AbstractCollection<E>
        java.util.AbstractList<E>
            java.util.Vector<E>
                java.util.Stack<E>
```

This means, that a Stack is more than a List (though it is one). It is a Vector.
From the Vector-class java-doc:

> The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Like an array, it contains components that can be accessed using an integer index. However, the size of a Vector can grow or shrink as needed to accommodate adding and removing items after the Vector has been created.

But there is more:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized.

Synchronized means an additional loss in efficiency (but usually neglectable).

So yes, if you only need the "storage" function, you can use an array and an offset for a minor gain in efficiency.